# Angular CLI version is not compatible with Angular version

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

My angular project was running fine but when I updated Angular to version 9 it started giving me this error:

```sh
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions 0.0.0 || ^10.0.0-beta || >=10.0.0 <11.0.0,
but Angular version 9.1.1 was found instead.
```

I updated the CLI but it is still giving me the same error.

My CLI version is:

```sh
Angular CLI: 10.0.0-next.0
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes
```

Comment: try to install nvm https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. it helps to manage multiple npm versions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The Problem

The CLI version you have installed doesn't meet the requirements for your Angular version as the error says:

```sh
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions 0.0.0 || ^10.0.0-beta || >=10.0.0 <11.0.0
```

### The Fix

Uninstall `@angular/cli` and be sure to install `@angular/cli` that is in the `9.1.x` version range so that it matches the requirements for the Angular 9.1 version.

```sh
Angular: 9.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
```

**Update Angular Project**

To uninstall and reinstall the `@angular/cli` package in your application, navigate to the root folder of the project and run the following:

```sh
# uninstall previous version
npm uninstall @angular/cli --save-dev

# install 9.1.x specific version
npm install @angular/cli@~9.1.0 --save-dev
```

> The `--save-dev` parameter will update your `package.json` devDependencies

**Update Global Dependency**

If you have installed `angular/cli` globally, you need to add `-g` at the end of the commands and omit the `--save-dev` parameter:

```sh
# uninstall previous globally installed version
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g

# install 9.1.x specific version globally
npm install @angular/cli@~9.1.0 -g
```

> If you are not sure what global version is installed (or if you have installed `@angular/cli` globally) you can run the following command to list your globally installed NPM packages:
>
> ```sh
> npm ls -g --depth=0
> ```

Comment: Uninstalling and installing globally a specific verion (in my case 11.2.18) works !

Comment: Unfortunately , this solution won't works for me , I'm getting this error : `npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/animations@9.1.13
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@11.0.9`

Answer (score 7):

You can update the project if you want it.

In the root project folder write:

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

This will upgrade the package.json file with the module versions installed in "node_modules" folder.

There are specific updating instructions depending from/to wich version do you want to update. Visit [Angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Visit  https://update.angular.io/
enter the details of your angular version to your targeted angular version, this would update the cli as well as the project files.
Just copy-paste the cmd then into the terminal and you're good to go.

Still, if you see some weird errors, check if the node_modules folder is present or not, if present then delete it and run - npm install
This might only work if you have the package.json file.
If you still get some error then see what the error says, delete the error line from package.json, and try once if working.